# Family Guy ep 113 (Road to Germany) scene explanation

Tags: family-guy

In Family Guy episode 113, Road to Germany, there is a scene where Stewie, Brian and Mort are in a bomber plane fighting nazi planes. They look to be out numbered, but then Stewie says something along the lines of, "No, we're going to make it" and it pans out to show a bunch of valkyrie type of warriors shooting laser weapons.

What are they referencing with the valkyrie warriors? Is it a movie? If so, which one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a reference to a scene from the movie [Flash Gordon](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080745/?ref_=sr_1). You can see the scene [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VnTHypbLlkE).

Comment: *"Flash...AAAAAHHH!"* - Amazing movie with an amazing title song. Now I'd really like to see the *Family Guy* version.